# Не могу выровнять картинку по горизонтали и вертикали

Tags: html, css

```css
body {
  font-family: 'Be Vietnam Pro', sans-serif;
  background-color: #000000;
}

.header-nav {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  font-weight: 600;
  font-size: 16px;
  line-height: 24px;
}

.header-logo {
  margin-left: 120px;
  margin-top: 40px;
  margin-right: auto;
}

.header-link {
  text-decoration: none;
  margin-top: 52px;
  letter-spacing: 0.01em;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  padding-right: 48px;
}

.header-btn {
  background-color: #EE8313;
  text-decoration: none;
  margin-right: 134px;
  margin-left: 86px;
  margin-top: 40px;
  padding: 12px 24px;
  letter-spacing: 0.01em;
  color: #FFFFFF;
}

.world-header {
  color: #FFFFFF;
  font-weight: 700;
  font-size: 52px;
  line-height: 64px;
  letter-spacing: 0.006em;
  max-width: 591px;
  margin-top: 167px;
  margin-left: 120px;
}

.world-text {
  font-weight: 400;
  font-size: 17px;
  line-height: 28px;
  letter-spacing: -0.408px;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  max-width: 474px;
  margin-top: 32px;
  margin-left: 120px;
}

.world-btn-buy {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 12px 24px;
  background-color: #EE8313;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  text-decoration: none;
  margin-left: 120px;
  margin-top: 48px;
  font-weight: 600;
  font-size: 16px;
  line-height: 24px;
  letter-spacing: 0.01em;
}

.world-btn-video {
  font-weight: 600;
  font-size: 16px;
  line-height: 24px;
  letter-spacing: 0.01em;
  color: #EE8313;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 12px 24px;
  margin-left: 35px;
  border: 1px solid #EE8313;
}

.world-bold-500 {
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-weight: 700;
  font-size: 40px;
  line-height: 52px;
  letter-spacing: -0.0041em;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  margin-top: 40px;
  margin-left: 120px;
}

.world-info-luxury {
  font-weight: 600;
  font-size: 16px;
  line-height: 24px;
  letter-spacing: 0.01em;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  margin-top: 61px;
  margin-left: 16px;
}

.world-block-luxury {
  display: flex;
}

.world-bold-1 {
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-weight: 700;
  font-size: 40px;
  line-height: 52px;
  letter-spacing: -0.0041em;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  margin-top: 40px;
  margin-left: 40px;
}

.world-info-best {
  font-weight: 600;
  font-size: 16px;
  line-height: 24px;
  letter-spacing: 0.01em;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  margin-top: 61px;
  margin-left: 16px;
}
```

```html
<header class="header">
  <nav class="header-nav">
    <img src="img/lgo.svg" alt="logo" class="header-logo">
    <a href="#" class="header-link">Home</a>
    <a href="#" class="header-link">Cars</a>
    <a href="#" class="header-link">Book now</a>
    <a href="#" class="header-link">Terms and Conditions</a>
    <a href="#" class="header-btn">Manage Booking</a>
  </nav>
</header>
<main class="main">
  <section class="world">
    <h1 class="world-header">The World's Best Luxury Car Deals</h1>
    <p class="world-text">HKinvestor can provide rentals of the most exclusive cars like Ferrari and Lamborghini.</p>
    <a href="#" class="world-btn-buy">Buy Now</a>
    <a href="#" class="world-btn-video">Video Introduction</a>
    <div class="world-block-luxury">
      <b class="world-bold-500">500+</b>
      <p class="world-info-luxury">Luxury Cars</p>
      <b class="world-bold-1">#1</b>
      <p class="world-info-best">Best Deal Car</p>
      <img src="img/world-img.png" alt="" class="world-img">
    </div>
  </section>
```

Как выглядит у меня
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как должно быть
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вообще на Youtube есть видео по этому макету, но там сделано через абсолютное позиционирование, а адаптив в ролике не делается, я хочу сделать адаптив, но не знаю можно ли потом будет сделать адаптив при абсолютном позиционировании, ещё перепробовал кучу других способов, по горизонтали вытаскивал картинку из блока и выровнял через флоат по правому краю , а по вертикали так и не сдвинул никаким способом.

Comment: Также сейчас в голову пришла интересная мысль, даже когда я ставил картинку в один блок со значением флекс, она всё равно уходила ниже, возможно просто размер слишком большой и она не помещается рядом с другими элементами в блоке?

Comment: во первых сделай отдельный блок для имг(там серый квадрат), будет легче с этим работать. Во вторых у тебя нет настроек этого изображения, оно само редко становится как надо

Comment: Я надеюсь вы просто учитесь, а не делаете проект, иначе могу посочувствовать вашему заказчику).

Comment: У вас не то что этот блок, а вся html разметка не правильная. Тут вам никакие стили не помогут. Вы пытаетесь с помощью стилей нивелировать недостатки html разметки. Во первых у вас должен быть .container для центрирования всей информации и её ровного отображения по вертикали. А вы сейчас отступ от края окна браузера делаете за счёт margin. Как вы хотите достичь центрирования в таком случае?

Comment: Ну единственное автомобиль выходит за рамки контейнера, а значит нужно изображение вытащить во внешний контейнер большей ширины.

Comment: @ЕвгенийЛи Я пока что только учусь.

Answer (score 0):

На флексах можно все что угодно сверстать

```css
body {
  font-family: 'Be Vietnam Pro', sans-serif;
  background-color: #000000;
}

.header-nav {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  font-weight: 600;
  font-size: 16px;
  line-height: 24px;
}

.header-logo {
  margin-left: 120px;
  margin-top: 40px;
  margin-right: auto;
}

.header-link {
  text-decoration: none;
  margin-top: 52px;
  letter-spacing: 0.01em;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  padding-right: 48px;
}

.header-btn {
  background-color: #EE8313;
  text-decoration: none;
  margin-right: 134px;
  margin-left: 86px;
  margin-top: 40px;
  padding: 12px 24px;
  letter-spacing: 0.01em;
  color: #FFFFFF;
}

.world-header {
  color: #FFFFFF;
  font-weight: 700;
  font-size: 52px;
  line-height: 64px;
  letter-spacing: 0.006em;
  max-width: 591px;
  margin-top: 167px;
  margin-left: 120px;
}

.world-text {
  font-weight: 400;
  font-size: 17px;
  line-height: 28px;
  letter-spacing: -0.408px;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  max-width: 474px;
  margin-top: 32px;
  margin-left: 120px;
}

.world-btn-buy {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 12px 24px;
  background-color: #EE8313;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  text-decoration: none;
  margin-left: 120px;
  margin-top: 48px;
  font-weight: 600;
  font-size: 16px;
  line-height: 24px;
  letter-spacing: 0.01em;
}

.world-btn-video {
  font-weight: 600;
  font-size: 16px;
  line-height: 24px;
  letter-spacing: 0.01em;
  color: #EE8313;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 12px 24px;
  margin-left: 35px;
  border: 1px solid #EE8313;
}

.world-bold-500 {
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-weight: 700;
  font-size: 40px;
  line-height: 52px;
  letter-spacing: -0.0041em;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  margin-top: 40px;
  margin-left: 120px;
}

.world-info-luxury {
  font-weight: 600;
  font-size: 16px;
  line-height: 24px;
  letter-spacing: 0.01em;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  margin-top: 61px;
  margin-left: 16px;
}

.world-block-luxury {
  display: flex;
}

.world-bold-1 {
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-weight: 700;
  font-size: 40px;
  line-height: 52px;
  letter-spacing: -0.0041em;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  margin-top: 40px;
  margin-left: 40px;
}

.world-info-best {
  font-weight: 600;
  font-size: 16px;
  line-height: 24px;
  letter-spacing: 0.01em;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  margin-top: 61px;
  margin-left: 16px;
}

.worldDiv {
  position: relative;
  width: 50%;
  min-height: 80vh;
  display: flex;
  align-items: flex-end;
  background: #3a3838;
}

.world-img {
  position: relative;
  left: -80px;
  width: 100%;
}

.main {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  align-items: flex-end;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <header class="header">
    <nav class="header-nav">
      <img src="img/lgo.svg" alt="logo" class="header-logo">
      <a href="#" class="header-link">Home</a>
      <a href="#" class="header-link">Cars</a>
      <a href="#" class="header-link">Book now</a>
      <a href="#" class="header-link">Terms and Conditions</a>
      <a href="#" class="header-btn">Manage Booking</a>
    </nav>
  </header>
  <main class="main">
    <section class="world">
      <h1 class="world-header">The World's Best Luxury Car Deals</h1>
      <p class="world-text">HKinvestor can provide rentals of the most exclusive cars like Ferrari and Lamborghini.</p>
      <a href="#" class="world-btn-buy">Buy Now</a>
      <a href="#" class="world-btn-video">Video Introduction</a>
      <div class="world-block-luxury">
        <b class="world-bold-500">500+</b>
        <p class="world-info-luxury">Luxury Cars</p>
        <b class="world-bold-1">#1</b>
        <p class="world-info-best">Best Deal Car</p>
      </div>
    </section>
    <div class="worldDiv"><img src="https://free-png.ru/wp-content/uploads/2020/11/hd-orange-audi-r8-car-png-24-ee2fa56d.png" alt="" class="world-img"></div>
    <script src="./script.js"></script>
</body>
```

Comment: Cпасибо огромное, код хоть и скопировал полностью, но у меня почему-то у меня картинка чуть выше встала, ну это ладно разберусь, главное понял принцип решения проблемы.